# Recommendation System on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: android

I am currently developing a mobile recommendation system on android and for the server part, the application uses Google Cloud Platform. I planned for the recommendation part to build a decision graph on server side but I do not know how to do it. Does anybody have any idea? If is is to difficult, what other method should I use for the recommendation part? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SparkML on Dataproc:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/recommendations-using-machine-learning-on-compute-engine

to build a recommendation system.